# How to keep you Windows Phone 7.5 application on top

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

we are creating a windows Phone 7.5 application, this application is developed for specific purpose for company field employes, phones will contain the data sim. No communication allowed like making a phone call, sending sms or chekcing and repling email etc. This application will receive the Push Notifications from our application in the head office.

Is there any way that we can keep this application always on top, regardless what button is pressed by the user we want this application to always stay on top so what ever the notification it receive it will always disply it to the user for futher action.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requirement is not really feasible for a couple of reasons. First, what you are describing actually breaks most of the concepts that a certified app is required to follow. A subset of certification details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=vs.92).aspx

Secondly, even if you planned to override the back button (possible) there really is no way to override the Windows, search or camera button at the OS level.

Best of luck!

Comment: And its good that this is not possible! Too many applications of Malware are possible with this, because it offers more Control.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: you can't. Application switching is part of the OS, and you don't have control over it.

Best workaround is to pin the app to start and allow it to do background processing with updates to the live tile.

If it's an absolute requirement, you'll have to jailbreak the phone and install your own OS on it.